# Migrating log4j 1.2.x to log4j 2.16.0

Tags: java, log4j2

Migrating log4j 1.2.x to log4j 2.16.0

Using PropertyConfigurator.configure method to load all log4j file are located at specific location on the system.

```
static {
   PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:/users/log4j.properties").
}
```

What is alternative way for configure log4j properties from external location?

What is alternative way of using PropertyConfigurator.configure in log4j2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure log4j with a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288876/how-to-configure-log4j-with-a-properties-file)

Comment: to load log4j.properties from external location.

Comment: Above link is specific to log4j 1.x version where we have support for PropertyConfigurator class. but in log4j 2.x this support is not exists then what should be approach to achieve the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PropertyConfigurator in log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043770/propertyconfigurator-in-log4j2)

Answer (score -1):

You have to do some code changes after adding new dependencies.

Add the following dependencies to the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

replace your java class file import `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;` with  `import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;` and `import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

then replace `private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);` with `private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);`

For further reference: [click here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)

Comment: As there is change in package structure from log4j1.x to log4j2.x so we have change these statement but my question is not related changing package

Comment: From Log4J 2's documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#reconfig_from_code